# Reciprocal of power series has a power series; Hunter

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, power-series

I'm reading these [lecture notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/intro_analysis_pdf/intro_analysis.html) by Hunter, specifically chapter 10 on power series, and I have some elementary questions about a proof on the proposition stating that the reciprocal of a convergent power series that is nonzero at its center also has a power series. Everything is real here. The following proposition is used in the proof:

> **Proposition 10.15.** If $R, S>0$ and the functions
> $$
> f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n} \quad \text { in }|x|<R, \quad g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_{n} x^{n} \quad \text { in }|x|<S
> $$
> are sums of convergent power series, then
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> (f+g)(x) & =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(a_{n}+b_{n}\right) x^{n} & & \text { in }|x|<T, \\
> (f g)(x) & =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n} x^{n} & & \text { in }|x|<T
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where $T=\min (R, S)$ and
> $$
> c_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{n-k} b_{k} .
> $$

Now follows the proposition and its proof that I have some questions about.

> **Proposition 10.16.** If $R>0$ and
> $$
> f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n} \quad \text { in }|x|<R,
> $$
> is the sum of a power series with $a_{0} \neq 0$, then there exists $S>0$ such that
> $$
> \frac{1}{f(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_{n} x^{n} \quad \text { in }|x|<S .
> $$
> The coefficients $b_{n}$ are determined recursively by
> $$
> b_{0}=\frac{1}{a_{0}}, \quad b_{n}=-\frac{1}{a_{0}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_{n-k} b_{k}, \quad \text { for } n \geq 1 .
> $$

> **Proof.** First, we look for a formal power series expansion (i.e., without regard to its convergence)
> $$
> g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_{n} x^{n}
> $$
> such that the formal Cauchy product $f g$ is equal to 1 . This condition is satisfied if
> $$
> \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_{n} x^{n}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{n-k} b_{k}\right) x^{n}=1 .
> $$
> Matching the coefficients of $x^{n}$, we find that
> $$
> a_{0} b_{0}=1, \quad a_{0} b_{n}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_{n-k} b_{k}=0 \quad \text { for } n \geq 1,
> $$
> which gives the stated recursion relation.
>
> To complete the proof, we need to show that the formal power series for $g$ has a nonzero radius of convergence. In that case, Proposition 10.15 shows that $f g=1$ inside the common interval of convergence of $f$ and $g$, so $1 / f=g$ has a power series expansion.

1. I'm a bit confused about the last paragraph. I don't see why $1/f=g$ has a power series expansion. The whole proposition is about showing that $1/f$ can be written as a power series. This has not been proven yet, right?

> We assume without loss of generality that $a_{0}=1$; otherwise replace $f$ by $f / a_{0}$.
> The power series for $f$ converges absolutely and uniformly on compact sets inside its interval of convergence, so the function
> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right||x|^{n}
> $$
> is continuous in $|x|<R$ and vanishes at $x=0$. It follows that there exists $\delta>0$ such that
> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right||x|^{n} \leq 1 \quad \text { for }|x| \leq \delta \tag{1}
> $$
> Then $f(x) \neq 0$ for $|x|<\delta$, since
> $$
> |f(x)| \geq 1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right||x|^{n}>0 \tag{2}
> $$
> so $1 / f(x)$ is well defined.

2. The author states a power series converges absolutely and uniformly on compact sets within its radius of convergence. The latter implies that a power series therefor is continuous within its radius of convergence. That said, I'd like to verify why $h(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right||x|^{n}$ is continuous, as claimed above. If $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ converges for $|x|<R$, so does $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right||x|^{n}$ on $|x|<R$ according to the author. $g(x)$ is just another power series, so it is continuous on $|x|<R$. Hence, since $a_0=1$, $h(x)=g(x)-1$ and this is continuous since it is the difference of two continuous functions. Is this reasoning correct?
3. I am a little confused about $(1)$ and $(2)$. I suppose $(1)$ is just the definition of continuity with $<$ replaced by $\leq$. However, where do the two inequalities in $(2)$ follow from? Why do they hold for $|x|<\delta$?

> We claim that
> $$
> \left|b_{n}\right| \leq \frac{1}{\delta^{n}} \quad \text { for } n=0,1,2, \ldots
> $$
> The proof is by induction. Since $b_{0}=1$, this inequality is true for $n=0$. If $n \geq 1$ and the inequality holds for $b_{k}$ with $0 \leq k \leq n-1$, then by taking the absolute value of the recursion relation for $b_{n}$, we get
> $$
> \left|b_{n}\right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|a_{k}\right|\left|b_{n-k}\right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\left|a_{k}\right|}{\delta^{n-k}} \leq \frac{1}{\delta^{n}} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{k}\right| \delta^{k} \leq \frac{1}{\delta^{n}},
> $$
> so the inequality holds for $b_{k}$ with $0 \leq k \leq n$, and the claim follows.
>
> We then get that
> $$
> \limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|b_{n}\right|^{1 / n} \leq \frac{1}{\delta}
> $$
> so the Hadamard formula in Theorem 10.6 implies that the radius of convergence of $\sum b_{n} x^{n}$ is greater than or equal to $\delta>0$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Could someone explain why on Earth this has 4 close votes?

Comment: @AShrike It seems that some vote to close because this question tackles multiple problems that one could argue could get their own questions. I don't necessarily agree but I don't necessarily disagree either, I'll stay neutral honestly.

Comment: @AShrike  Some people just want to see things burn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Read the statement of proposition again, specifically this part "*then there exists $S>0$ such that $\frac{1}{f(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_{n} x^{n}$ in $|x|<S$.*" You're trying to prove that such $S$ exists not that $1/f$ can be written as power series, that part is already assumed.
2. Yes, you're reasoning is correct. You can [check here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750160/prove-that-the-sum-of-two-continuous-functions-is-continuous) for more details.
3. $(2)$ comes from the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right||x|^{n} \leq 1$ for $|x|\le \delta$ $(1)$. Obviously $|f(x)|=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right||x|^{n}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right||x|^{n}\ge1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right||x|^{n}$ from $(1)$ you get $1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right||x|^{n} \ge0$ for $\delta<0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Here was my reasoning about 3, which I think is somewhat different from yours: 
$$\begin{align}|f(x)|&=\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}\right| \\ &=\left|1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n\right| \\ &\geq \left|1-\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n\right|\right| \\ &\geq 1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n||x|^n \\ &\geq 0. \end{align}$$
The first inequality is the reverse triangle inequality, the second follows from $(1)$ and that $\left|\sum a_n \right|\leq \sum |a_n|$ and the third is $(1)$ again.

Comment: Yes, you're correct I've edited my answer. I accidentaly wrote that the series starts from 1 instead of 0. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Like the OP, I'm not convinced by the argument *"In that case, Proposition 10.15 shows that $f g=1$ inside the common interval of convergence of $f$ and $g$, so $1 / f=g$ has a power series expansion."* What if the common interval of convergence is empty? The proof should state why that can't happen.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123642/if-the-radius-of-convergence-of-the-power-series-a-is-positive-then-it-recipr) contains a convincing proof using induction.